# Pointer to 3D Arrays of Pointer

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create a Pointer to a dynamic 3D Array full of Pointers. I'm working with Voxel, so let's say that `t_cube` is my object.

First, I tried doing this:

```
t_cube* (*m_Array)[][][];
```

I thought I could do like

```
m_Array = new t_cube[sizeX][sizeZ][sizeY];
```

Compiling this failed, however.

Next I tried this:

```
t_cube *(m_Model[]); // This is my .h
{
    t_cube *model_Tempo[sizeX][sizeZ][sizeY]; // And this is in my class constructor.
    m_Model = model_Tempo;
}
```

Again, this failed to compile.

Comment: It may be in your best interest to use vectors. ie `vector<vector<vector<t_cube*>>>`. This would remove the need to manually de/allocate memory

Comment: Have you tried constructing a 2D array of `int`?

Comment: I tried but I really need the 3D Array to work. I'm working on a 3D Voxel Editor and I need to create, move and remove cube where I want. I would use the array as the position of each cube if you understand what I mean. I really need to be able to play in it easily.

Comment: You say your code failed to compile; just looking at it I can guess why, but what specifically did it tell you was the error and how did you try and fix it?

Comment: Well, the first error was, saying that and Array of type cannot be of this specific size. Then I tried the second way which created the "expression need to be a modifiable value" error. Which i'm still trying to solve right now.

Comment: @GabrielRoy: please provide the (full) list of relevant errors; the exact name of the error can provide additional information.

Comment: When declaring a multi-dimensional array, you need to specify the bounds for all the dimensions except the first one.  Also provide the errors that you are getting.

Comment: @GabrielRoy `I tried but I really need the 3D Array to work. I'm working on a 3D Voxel Editor and I need to create, move and remove cube where I want. I`  So how does that invalidate the usage of vectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this example would be helpful to solve your problem:

Since, we are dealing with **Pointer of 3-D Array**. So, if I write it in C++ grammar, it would be like:

```
t_cube *array[x_size][y_size][z_size];
```

But, you already mentioned, it fails to execute.
Now, do the same thing using Dynamic Allocation Approach.

```
t_cube ****array;                // Since, it a pointer to the 3D Array
array = new t_cube ***[x_size];
for(int i=0; i<x_size; i++) {
    array[i] = new t_cube **[y_size];
    for(int j =0; j<y_size; j++) {
        array[i][j] = new t_cube *[z_size];
    }
}                                /*  I'm sure this will work */
```

And, the reasons you were facing trouble:

1. The size of the **m_Array** could be very large :  ***x_size* * *y_size* * *z_size* * *sizeof(t_cube)*** .
2. You must have defined **m_Array** locally (inside the function), which is the major reason of program malfunction.

Comment: This is good. But does it actually create an array in which I will be able to access simply by doing this: m_array[1][1][1]->method;
Because how I see it, what will happen is that this is an array within an array within another array linked with pointer so I will need to use m_array[1]->[1]->[1]->method: ?

Comment: No. simply use *(m_array[i][j][k]) to retrieve the value. But, it will only return the value if and only if it is set to point to value before. Otherwise, runtime Error. It means, after initialization, set the pointers of 3D matrix to any valid value address, after that use it wherever and whenever you what to use.